# Como mostrar o meu celular no vs2017 e compilar com ele?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Hoje uso o vysor para criar minhas aplicações. Sem o Vysor, eu não consigo visualizar o meu cell(J500M) na barra de debug do VS2017. Existe outra forma de eu plugar qualquer celular e aparecer no VS2017 sem uso de aplicativos de terceiros?

Comment: O AVD é um dispositivo virtual. Você está se refererindo ao dispositivo real e quer espelhá-lo no computador usando o VS?

Comment: @vnbrs, isso mesmo, o real. Vou editar o post para não confundir. O que eu quero é plugar qualquer celular e aparecer na tela do VS.

Comment: Acho que de forma nativa não tenha como. Existem algumas alternativas de _mirroring_ grátis se forem do seu interesse.

Comment: E como eu vejo isso, @vnbrs. Tem um link que possa me ajudar?

Comment: O Vysor não resolve pra você? O próprio Vysor é uma ferramenta de espelhamento / _mirroring_.

Comment: Resolve, é que começo a desconfiar de tudo, pois parece que está ok, mas existe algo que barra o recebimento. No anti virus, os app's que crio, estão liberados para receber mensagens, mas mesmo assim ainda desconfio desse cara: **Security Master**, @vnbrs